# Geocoder grpc failed [none of the solution on stackoverflow worked]

Tags: android, geocoder

I am trying to get address from latitude & longitude but it throws an exception with a message "grpc failed".

I know there are many same questions on stackoverflow but none of the solution/answer worked for me.

Logcat:

```
01-03 09:46:12.230 30098-30340/ W/System.err:     java.io.IOException: grpc failed
01-03 09:46:12.230 30098-30340/ W/System.err:     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
01-03 09:46:12.230 30098-30340/ W/System.err:     at com.akshay.location.gps.AKLocationRequest$startLocationUpdates$1$onLocationResult$$inlined$let$lambda$1.run(AKLocationRequest.kt:67)
01-03 09:46:12.230 30098-30340/ W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
01-03 09:46:12.230 30098-30340/ W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
01-03 09:46:12.231 30098-30340/ W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
01-03 09:46:12.231 30098-30340/W/System.err:      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Are you using this application on emulator ?

Comment: No, I'm facing this issue on real device

Comment: please add device info

Comment: LG Nexus 5X - 8.1 Oero

Comment: Have you installed `google play services` in your device ?

Comment: Yes, Google play services are already installed